How to use QuickSort in JS to sort an array with objects by object's properties (i.e. color, name) in accordance with a given property order
I have an array filled with objects "fruits" which have properties "kind", "color". I need to use
quicksort 

method to sort given fruits by their colors in accordance to a given order of colors.
For example, an array "fruits" has
 {kind: apple, color: red}; {kind: orange, color: orange}; {kind: watermelon, color: green}; {kind: blueberry, color: blue}.

And you need to sort these fruits in accordance to rainbow color orders. How do we do that? All examples, that I have found on the internet only deal with numbers. I know that first step is to make a function which tells us the weight of a color in a given order:
const comparationColor = (fruit1, fruit2) => {
  const priority = ['violet', 'indigo', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red'];
  const priority1 = priority.indexOf(fruit1.color);
  const priority2 = priority.indexOf(fruit2.color);
  return priority1 > priority2;
};  

And then there is a
quickSort 

function:
quickSort (arr) {
    if (arr.length < 2) {
        return arr;
    }
    
      let pivot = arr[0];
      let leftArr = [];
      let rightArr = [];
    
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (comparation(pivot, arr[i])) {
          leftArr.push(arr[i]);
        } else {
          rightArr.push(arr[i]);
        }
      }
      return [...quickSort(leftArr), pivot, ...quickSort(rightArr)];
      }

But how do I combine them?

What's the expected output? See this? if (comparationColor(pivot, arr[i]) > 0)?

Why would you do that with quick sort? When you have a limited set of keys, like 7 colors, then you're much better off by creating 7 buckets in the order of the rainbow colors, and then you can store all objects in their proper bucket. At the end concatenate those buckets. Done.

Because it's an assignment. And it's not particularly 7 colors, that's for an example, there could be 15 colors or any other property and you set any order of this property, and quicksort should sort an array according to that order.
